# how to store measurement data for further processing?

Tags: machine-learning, logic, signal-processing

I am new to this forum and I welcome any advice regarding forum etiquettes.

I am working on this project where I measure a bunch of impedance's at different fixed frequencies(let's say 6). I would like to store them in a buffer of fixed size (lets say 20) and then use them later for further calculations. There could be a case when I get one measurement at 1 Hz after 100 measurements at 100Hz. I don't want to wait for all the 100 values to start processing my data but data of all the frequencies is needed to finish processing. Now, I am confused how to store them. Below are two possible solutions:

1.) I take the mean of measured data and store them separately. Here, depending on the measured frequency, I may have just 2 values from 20 measurements or if I'm lucky then I get all 6.

2.) I put some weights on the measured data before storing them into buffer. A lower weight for the higher frequencies and then use all 20 measurements for further processing. I guess the weights would depend on the buffer size but I'm not sure how will it work.

Please recommend me a better solution.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you actually want to do with the data. Without it we can't give answers. I mean, if the goal was to find the mean, we could process data without any buffer (buffer of 1 value)

Without more context we can only say: "store everything into a file" cause we dont know what is needed and what is not

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I should have been more lucid. I have a set of values arriving from measurements at different frequencies. I must either store everything into a file and once I have measurements for all the six frequencies, I use it to fit my curve. Alternately I can use a buffer such that every time there are at least measurements available for 3 frequencies (obviously higher frequencies) and I try to fit my curve once  after the buffer is full each time. I think it makes more sense as it would distribute the calculation effort alongside providing the more latest set of parameters.